# Apache lists directory files instead of index.php

Tags: php, apache, directoryindex

My Apache web server suddenly stopped serving index.php files automatically. It shows direcotry listing instead. I've tried helps but no luck.

My htttpd.conf file includes

```
<IfModule module_php5>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfMOdule>
```

and

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

What could be wrong if all above are OK?

Comment: Note that tags stand alone.  That is, combining `directory` and `index` doesn't mean the same thing as `directoryindex`.  Please pick tags with care.

Comment: What if you request `index.php` explicitly?

Comment: @Charles, I specifically wanted to tag directory and index separately. but thanks for editing the codes.

Comment: @zerkms the browser shows index.php when typed explicitly.

Comment: I am new to this site. I've read threads before, but didn't have an account until recently. So I don't know any common practice in asking questions, but will learn by time. Can I ask why you deleted "thanks in advance" from the end of my question, @Charles ?

Comment: @mavili, thanks for asking about that!  We have an entire site dedicated to discussions about SO -- click the "meta" link in the header.  You'll want to [read this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/135887) to understand why greetings and thanks are frequently removed.  There's a [whole separate FAQ on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) in fact.  Also, SO is *not* a forum, it is place to ask questions and get answers. Treating it like a forum is a bad idea.

Comment: In regards to your problem, did you modify `DirectoryIndex`?  If so, did you restart Apache after changing the configuration?

Comment: @Charles I modified `DirectoryIndex` and restarted apache. It didn't change anything.

Answer (score 7):

I was surprised by the quick response when I first asked the question, and then the replies stopped! So I found the answer myself (by accident!). The main server root displayed index files fine, it was my user Sites folder that did not.

There is a .conf file for each user in apache users directory. I added

```
<Directory "/Users/mavili/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks SymLinksIfOwnerMatch Includes ExecCGI
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.pl index.cgi
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

into the file for my username and tata, it worked!