# Why Laravel is showing me the directory structure?

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess

I had reinstalled apache and after I configured it again, my Laravel applications don't work anymore and it shows me the directory structure instead.[image]

Here is my httpd configuration:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache lists directory files instead of index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898386/apache-lists-directory-files-instead-of-index-php)

Comment: i have already tried that but same result

Comment: Please share your attempts through editing the question

Answer (score 1):

If you've "reinstalled Apache" then the *default* `DirectoryIndex` is just `index.html`. You need this set to `index.php` in order to serve your Laravel front-controller.

When Apache does not find the `DirectoryIndex` document (eg. `index.html`) when requesting a directory and directory indexes/listings (mod_autoindex) are enabled (the default) then Apache generates a directory listing as you are seeing here.

You need to set `index.php` as the `DirectoryIndex`, for example:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/wafacashapp>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
```

Alternatively, you can set the `DirectoryIndex` in your `.htaccess` file - if you have one. (If you aren't using `.htaccess` files then you should disable `.htaccess` overrides by setting `AllowOverride None`.)

You should also consider disabling directory indexes/listings, so as to not expose the contents of your directories should a `DirectoryIndex` document not be found. For example, in the same `<Directory>` container (or `.htaccess` file):

```
Options -Indexes
```

The user will then be served a 403 Forbidden instead of a directory listing.

Answer (score -2):

you can add .htaccess file to root's of project and add these lines

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I would also disable indexes altogether as a precaution if this is a production environment as you don't want people inadvertently being able to browse directory structure, .htaccess `Options -Indexes`.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why exactly should that help? What makes you think that the application is structured such that this rule works?

Comment: laravel index.php is in public directory and maybe there is other's rule to handle it but I fixed this issue by htaccess and these codes

Comment: the htacces is located in public folder of the laravel project and i already when i open the application it shows the public directory

Comment: yes, htaccess is located in public ,  but url should be like `http://example.com/public` and if user call without public , directories will shown. so we can add htaccess file to root

Comment: when i add /public it show me this:
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *

 */

 Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
.our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';