# How do i display my laravel project's homepage instead of the list of files in the directory?

Tags: php, laravel, macos, xampp, localhost

I am working on a laravel project locally using XAMPP and when i input the url http://localhost/l10-task-list in my browser i get the list of files in the directory. To access the actual project I always have to add '/public' at the end of the url. Is there something I can do somehow to get my project to immediately redirect to the homepage when the url is http://localhost/l10-task-list?

I've researched already and tried everything - manipulated the httpd.conf, my host files, and my httpd-vhosts but nothing seems to want to work. :(

I initially started working on this project on a windows laptop and the http://localhost/l10-task-list url used to work perfectly. I have now switched to a MAC. Do not know if this information is relevant but just putting it out there.

Thanks.

I've already edited my hosts files and edit my httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts but nothing seems to want to work.

My apache2/conf/httpd.conf:

```
cleAlias /bitnami/ "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My httpd.conf (in etc/extra):

```
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/l10-task-list/public"
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs">
```

My httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/l10-task-list/public"
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/l10-task-list/public">
        AllowOverride All
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache lists directory files instead of index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898386/apache-lists-directory-files-instead-of-index-php)

Comment: You need to change your root dir in Apache2 conf and append public to it

Comment: @hassan in my apache2/conf/httpd.conf this is all I have:

cleAlias /bitnami/ "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: @hassan
In my httpd-vhosts.conf i've added this:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/l10-task-list/public"
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/l10-task-list/public">
        AllowOverride All
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Are you sure you'd restarted your web server?

Comment: @hassan Yep absolutely, several times :(

Comment: According to your configure, you are using `http://localhost` to serve your application while you are trying to access it using `http://localhost/l10-task-list`, can you visit the link `http://localhost` and check? also try to change the ServerName from localhost to use any other virtual host

Comment: Hey @hassan I restarted my laptop and it worked lol ... how silly. Thankyou very very much for your help anyway!